# Github, how to add license of fonts I am using in a project?

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0, github

A while back I made a game and uploaded it's project files on Github and added a MIT license to it. So I was just looking at it and realized that the font I am using in it had some sort of license file included in it when I first downloaded it. And in my github project, I forgot to add that license file. Nevertheless, I went to Google fonts from where I downloaded the font. It was this one -

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

And it has an Apache License, Version 2.0. But the thing is that in the license file there is this field where I don't understand what it says. It seems like it is asking us to write our name, their name or what. It is very confusing. Also it asks for a notice, which I kinda get it. But still I am very confused how to add it to my project. Because I don't want to get into any legal trouble.
So can I just put the license text file into the folder of the fonts?

But the problem is in the license, nowhere it says it is of Google or Open Sans. That's the thing. The license included with the fonts, looks more of like a blueprint to me.

And talking of that, I also realized that since I made this game using Godot Engine which is under MIT license. So I assume I have to put the license of that as well? So how will I add it??

Comment: Where is the license file?

Comment: If you'll download the font from the link provided, there would be a zip file. In there you will see the font's Apache license. Problem is that in the ending paragraphs, there is this line - "Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]" which makes no sense. I don't know what to do with it. It rather seems like a blueprint to me.

Comment: In the ending paragraphs where it says "HOW TO APPLY THE APACHE LICENSE TO YOUR WORK"?

Comment: Yes after that paragraph only!

Comment: This part of the license tells you HOW TO APPLY THE APACHE LICENSE TO YOUR WORK. Are you trying to APPLY THE APACHE LICENSE TO YOUR WORK?

Comment: My github project is a game's project files (made in Godot). I have also added an additional MIT license to it. But in my project, I am using OpenSans fonts. So I have these .ttf font files of OpenSans in my github project too. And as these files are not created by me, and also they are under Apache license, so I guess I will need to add the license provided by the fonts. Right?

But then, the license provided by the font is really vague, and nowhere tells that... that license belongs to Google/OpenSans. And rather looks like a blueprint to me.

Comment: And yes, I have done no changes to the font files itself. They are there, just because it is required to have them in order to render those fonts in the game engine.

Comment: You don't need to *add* the license provided by the fonts, you need to *follow* the license provided by the fonts. (of course, if the license says you must add it, then you must add it in order to follow it)

Comment: Thank You for the clarification. But I don't know what license really says. I saw some forum posts when searching through Google, where people said we have to include the license file for Apache 2.0. So if that's the case, then should I just put that license file provided by the font? And the reason I am confused is because the text in the license doesn't say anything about the font itself, and I am worried that... what if someone thinks that the license I am adding is not for the font but for my project. Which in reality is ofcourse not the case. But I am just too paranoid about this stuff.

Comment: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 <- the part in the square is what the license really says.

Comment: Yes I have read it, but I am still confused. Sorry to ask same questions again and again. But do you know what I should do here? For now though, I am thinking of just adding a text file telling from where I downloaded the files I don't own ( in this case, the font ). But other than that, should I add the license file provided with the font to my github repo or not?

Comment: You should do the things which the license says you must do. See section 4. Which one are you confused about?

Comment: I think since I am using font in my project, but haven't modified it. So it comes under the work category (meaning not a derived work)? So based on that, according to section 4 -

Comment: a) I should put the license file provided with the fonts. Right?

Comment: b) - I think that doesn't apply in my case. Because I haven't modified the files.

Comment: c) I believe this point too doesn't apply in my case. Though I am not totally sure.

Comment: d), I don't understand much. The fonts doesn't have any notice file. So I guess I shouldn't worry about it right?

Comment: You should do what the license says. It seems that you've now read the license and you know what it tells you to do.

Comment: Well I have added the license file to my project. It's just that I am still confused about the part why the font author didn't wrote their name in the license. So that's why just to be on the safe side, I added an additional readme file where I clearly stated that the font didn't belong to me as well as mentioned it's license file path in the project.

Comment: As an additional note, it seems like most of the other fonts too from Google which I tested so far, also didn't had the author name written. And that is totally confusing. But anyways, I am not gonna be paranoid about that crap. As far as my project is concerned, I think I did all the necessary steps correct, as the license said. Thank You for taking your time :)